# MongoDB on Azure operational cost

Tags: mongodb, azure

We are using MongoDB as a virtual machine (A3) on Azure. We are trying to simulate running cost of using MongoDB for our following scenario:

Scenario is to insert/update around 2k amount of data (time series data) every 5 minutes by 100,000 customers. We are using MongoDB on A3 instance (4 core) of Windows Server on Azure (that restricts 4TB per shard).

When we estimated running cost, it is coming out to be approx $34,000 per month - which includes MongoDB licensing, our MongoDB virtual machine, storage, backup storage and worker role.

This is way costly. We have some ideas to bring the cost down but need some advice on those ideas as some of you may have already done this.

Two questions:
1- As of today, we are estimating to use 28 MongoDB instances (with 4 TB limit). I have read that we can increase the disk size from 4TB to 64 TB on Linux VM or Windows Server 2012 server. This may reduce our number of shards needed. Is running MongoDB on 64TB disk size shard possible in Azure?

You may ask why 28 number of instances..

2- We are calculating our number of shards required based on "number of inserts per core"; which is itself depend on number of values inserted in the MongoDB per message. each value is 82 bytes. We did some load testing and it comes out that we can only run 8000 inserts per second and each core can handle approx. 193 inserts per second - resulting into need of 41 cores (which is way too high). You can divide 41 cores/4 resulting into A3 11 instances -- which is another cost....

Looking for help to see - if our calculation is wrong or the way we have setup is wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If all those data are real, you should not put your question here! You should rather immediately contact a local Microsoft representative in the Country where you live and get a direct advice from them. I am sure they will be happy to help you, and even offer you an Enterprise agreement (http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/licensing-options/enterprise.aspx#tab=3) which may have some discount!

Comment: Thank you @astaykov. We are in touch with our Microsoft representative and will be working with them. I am still looking for answer to question#1- Can I run MongoDB VM on Azure with 64TB as a disk size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question nr. 1:

> 1- As of today, we are estimating to use 28 MongoDB instances (with 4
>   TB limit). I have read that we can increase the disk size from 4TB to
>   64 TB on Linux VM or Windows Server 2012 server. This may reduce our
>   number of shards needed. Is running MongoDB on 64TB disk size shard
>   possible in Azure?

According to [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn197896.aspx), the maximum you can achieve is 16TB, which is 16 Data disks attached, max. 1 TB each. So, technically the largest disk you can attach is 1TB, but you can build RAID 0 stripe with the 16 disks attached, so you can get 16TB storage. But this (16TB) is the maximum amount of storage you can officially get.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Azure documentation A3 size can have a maximum of 8 data disks. So a maximum of 8TB. A4 can handle 16 disks. I would assume your bottleneck here is disk and not the number of cores. So i'm not convinced you need such a big cluster.